# Fragmented sentence

Tags: dialogue, structure, grammar

I have a book I am writing, and every time I go into a grammar fixing program, I get a lot of "Fragmented Sentences." Can some one explain to me how to fix these with out losing any part of the sentence I have?

I have looked this up, but for some reason it is not hitting home on what everyone is explaining.

Comment: Remember that the computer sometimes says something is a fragment which isn't. Also, at times you want fragments, for example, one word sentences for effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sentence has a subject and a verb, sometimes an object.

> He recites. (Subject: he; Verb: recites)
>
> She throws a book. (Subject: She; Verb: throws; Object: a book)

A sentence fragment is missing some part of that.

> Ran down the street. (Verb: ran; no subject)
>
> His impossibly high cheekbones. (Object: cheekbones; no subject or verb)
>
> Full of stars. (Just a descriptive clause; there's neither subject, verb, or object)

Generally a sentence fragment means you have to *add* something, not remove something. You might have to edit your question to include some examples, and we can show you what's missing from them.